# Reading data from database

Tags: html, jsp

In my program, I have a user enter their ticket number into an html form which connects to a jsp page that is supposed to get the information from the database and populate it into the table I created. Instead I only get a print out of the header that I made and the form with the button down on the bottom. It prints out an error code found in the catch statement. Can someone help me figure out how to fix this issue. I've messed around with the code for a while now. Please help?

Thanks soo much. This is the last step in my project...

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD><TITLE>Ticket Information</TITLE></HEAD>
 <BODY>

 <p>Ticket Information
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<TABLE BORDER=1 width="75%">
<TR><TH>Ticket</TH><TH>Date</TH><TH>Equipment</TH><TH>Description</TH><TH>Employee</TH><TH>Technician</TH></TR>
<%
  Connection con = null;
  Statement st = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  String tix = request.getParameter("Enter Ticket Number");
  String ticketlkup;


  try 
  {
    //load the Driver
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

    //Create a connection to the "emp" database
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/helpdesk?user=root&password=password");

    //Create a Statement object
    st = con.createStatement();

    //Create a ResultSet object and store the results of the query execution
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from ticket1 where t_id= " + tix +";");




%>
<TR><TD><%= rs.getString("t_id") %></TD>
<TD><%= rs.getString("t_date") %></TD>
<TD><%= rs.getString("t_equipment") %></TD>
<TD><%= rs.getString("t_descript") %></TD>
<TD><%= rs.getString("emp_id") %></TD>
<TD><%= rs.getString("tech_id") %></TD>
</TR>



<%
  } //end of try block
  catch (java.sql.SQLException ex) 
  {
    ex.printStackTrace();
%>
</TABLE>
Ooops, something bad happened:
<%
  } //end of catch block 
  finally
  {
    if (rs != null) rs.close();
    if (st != null) st.close();
    if (con != null) con.close();
  } //end of finally block

%>

</p>

<FORM method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/finalproject/helpdeskhome.html" >
<p>Click on the button to go back to the main page </p>
<button type="submit">Home</button>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: whats the error your try block throwing ?

Comment: please post your errors..

Answer (score 0):

Before you start using your resultset you have to call `rs.next()` because when you have just executed the query, you are not yet on the first row. `rs.next()` obviously will return `false` if there are no rows (or no rows left).

```
  try
  {
    ...
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from ticket1 where t_id= " + tix +";");
    if(rs.next())
    {
   %>
    <TR><TD><%= rs.getString("t_id") %></TD>
    <TD><%= rs.getString("t_date") %></TD>
    <TD><%= rs.getString("t_equipment") %></TD>
    <TD><%= rs.getString("t_descript") %></TD>
    <TD><%= rs.getString("emp_id") %></TD>
    <TD><%= rs.getString("tech_id") %></TD>
    </TR>
  <%
    } //end of if
    else
    {
        out.print("<TR><TD colspan='6'>No Rows</TD></TR>");
    }
  } //end of try block
```